# c# LINQ to XML - XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

Just trying to read a simple XML doc in using `XDocument` class.
The document is read, but I'm struggling mapping my `OperationConfig` to the XML?

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(path);
var query = xml.Root.Elements("configaccount")
    .Select(o => new OperationConfig()
    {
        AccountName = o.Attribute("accountname").Value,
        Email = o.Attribute("email").Value
    });
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <configaccount>
            <accountname>
                BusinessName
            </accountname>
            <email>
                aa@domain.com
            </email>
        </configaccount>
    </Config>
```

Not sure what I've missed as I'm retuning null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrive Descendants node by name from xml. Also "accountname" and "email" is not an attributes, its an Element of XML. Attributes are inside element.

Replace your query

```
 var query = xml.Descendants("configaccount")
        .Select(o => new OperationConfig
        {
            AccountName = o.Element("accountname").Value,
            Email = o.Element("email").Value
        });
```

Hope this help

Comment: You might consider adding *why* this query works and why the original one didn't.  I don't think much will be learnt by simply copy and pasting your solution.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMager, I have improved my answer.