# Get Child Node value using parent Node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, default-namespace

How to Get the Value of the node by using the parent tag name.

Here is my XML format.

```
<ListOrderItemsResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
 <ListOrderItemsResult>
   <AmazonOrderId>Order Id</AmazonOrderId>
 <OrderItems>
   <OrderItem>
     <ASIN>Asin Value</ASIN>
     <SellerSKU>SKU</SellerSKU>
     <OrderItemId>SKU Value</OrderItemId>
     <Title>Product Title</Title>
     <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
     <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
     <ItemPrice>
         <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
         <Amount>30.00</Amount>
     </ItemPrice>
     <ShippingPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>5.00</Amount>
     </ShippingPrice>
  </OrderItem>
</OrderItems>
</ListOrderItemsResult>
```

How to get Item Price Amount and Shipping Price Amount.

Here i tried so far..

Method 1:

```
XmlNode node12 = xd1.SelectSingleNode("/ListOrderItemsResponse[@*]/ListOrderItemsResult/OrderItems/OrderItem/ItemPrice");
string id = node12["Amount"].InnerText;
```

Method 2:

```
int i = 0;
                XmlNodeList nodeAMT = xd1.GetElementsByTagName("Amount");
                string[] AMT = new string[TotalCount];
                foreach (XmlElement node in nodeAMT)
                {
                    AMT[i] = node.InnerText;
                    i++;
                }
```

How to Get ItemPrice 30 and ShippingPrice 5.

Any Suggestions??

Comment: You can also use linq-to-xml try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912156/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-xdocument/36912524#36912524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical problem of *default namespace*. Your XML has default namespace declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01"
```

All elements without prefix are considered in the above mentioned default namespace. To select element in namespace, you need to use `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
//register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01");

string query = "/d:ListOrderItemsResponse/d:ListOrderItemsResult/d:OrderItems/d:OrderItem/d:ItemPrice/d:Amount";
XmlNode node = xd1.SelectSingleNode(query, nsmgr);
string itemPrice = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: I get the Error : Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.  in XmlNode node = xd1.SelectSingleNode(query) line

Comment: oops.. forgot to pass the namespace manager to `SelectSingleNode()`

Comment: Object Reference Error in string itemPrice = node.InnerText.

Comment: Remove attribute predicate `[@*]` from the XPath. The root element has no attribute but namespace declaration. I'm sure this should work now, see the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/0W0tRn

Answer (score 1):

With the second method, you can use the XmlElement Parent property, to get the name of the parent.

```
 XmlNodeList amounts = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Amount");
            foreach (XmlElement amount in amounts)
            {
                if (amount.ParentNode != null)
                {
                    if (amount.ParentNode.Name.Equals("ItemPrice"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Item Price"+amount.InnerText);
                    }
                    if (amount.ParentNode.Name.Equals("ShippingPrice"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Shipping Price" + amount.InnerText);

                    }
                }
            }
```

I hope this can help you.